# Помогите реализовать Метод Set и Insert

Tags: java

Помогите докончить код. Это метод Set и метод Insert (Set изменять элемент, Insert Вставить элемент). Помогите реализовать эти методы.
Буду благодарен!

```
public class DynamicArrays implements List {

    private int length;
    private Object[] items;

    public DynamicArrays() {
        length = 0;
        items = new Object[length];
    }
    @Override
    public void add(Object item) {
        length += 1;
        Object[] old = items;
        items = new Object[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
            items[i] = old[i];
        items[length - 1] = item;
    }

    @Override
    public long size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return length;
    }

    public void remove(int index) {
        for (int i = index; i < length - 1; i++)
            items[i] = items[i + 1];
        length--;
    }

    public Object get(int index) {
        if (index < length)
            return items[index];
        return null;
    }

    public void set(Object item, int index) {

    }

    public void insert(Object item, int index) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

На скорую руку сделал так

```
public void set(Object item, int index) {
    items[index] = item;
}

public void insert(Object item, int index) {
    length += 1;
    Object[] temp = items;
    items = new Object[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
        items[i] = temp[i];
    items[index] = item;
    for (int i = index + 1; i < length; ++i)
        items[i] = temp[i];
}
```